# Backbone JSON collection to template output

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I asked a question on this yesterday which helped alot.

I have rewrote most of the code by following tutorials and youtube videos as well as help on stackoverflow however i am unsure what i am doing wrong when pushing the JSON data to the underscore template.

Basically i want to take the data from the json array, loop through it and display it. I've seen tutorials that do this through .get but weren't using an json array. Any help is appreciated.

My code looks like this: (I've put a comment on the line i guess things are going wrong)

```
<body>
  <div class="News"></div>

  <script type="text/template" id="NewsTemplate">
    <table>                
      <% _.each(NewsCollection, function(item) { %>           
        <tr>
          <td><%= item.title %></td>
        </tr>          
      <% }); %>   
    </table>
  </script>

  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var NewsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ });

    // backbone collection, gather google news json array
    var NewsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      url: 'data.js'
    })

    var NewsList = Backbone.View.extend({               
      el: '.News',
      template: _.template($("#NewsTemplate").html()),             
      render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var NewsItems = new NewsCollection();
          NewsItems.fetch({

          //guessing im doing something wrong here?

          success: function (NewsItems) {
            $(this.el).html(that.template({'collection.toJSON': NewsItems.toJSON()}));
          }
        })
      }                
    });       

    // Backbone router do action on homepage load
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({            
      routes: {
        '': 'home'  
      }            
    });

    var newslist = new NewsList();           

    var router = new Router();          
    router.on('route:home' , function (){
      newslist.render();
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :
Replace following lines

```
success: function (NewsItems) {
  $(this.el).html(that.template({'collection.toJSON': NewsItems.toJSON()}));
}
```

with

```
success: function (NewsItems) {
  $(this.el).html(that.template({ newsItems: NewsItems.toJSON()}));
}
```

Update template as:

```
  <script type="text/template" id="NewsTemplate">
    <table>                
      <% _.each(newsItems, function(item) { %>           
        <tr>
          <td><%= item.title %></td>
        </tr>          
      <% }); %>   
    </table>
  </script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply :) I made those amendments but i'm not sure its even reaching the template part. I can place a <h1>test</h1> in it and it doesn't even show that. If that makes sense?

Comment: Ye there seems to be an Object there. 

[Object]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

On some refreshes it doesn't seem to appear though. It's there about 80% of the time :o

Comment: Now it is clear that your template is fine. Since you are getting empty Array. Put another debug line in success function as 'console.log(NewsItems.toJSON());'.

Comment: Just did that and the array is also empty. Does that mean is something to do with the JSON or how im pulling it in?

Comment: Please check your url "url: 'data.js'". Also, update route as "'/': 'home'"

Comment: Hey thanks for all your help budhram. When i update the route to '/:home' it no longer seems to work. When i pull up the control panel on chrome and go to Network -> XHR i can see the JSON file is being loaded

Comment: also when i do console.log(JSON.stringify(NewsItems)); instead, i can see all the JSON in a string.